# How do I get many computers acting as one

Tags: multiple-computers

I have some old computers [Apple Blueberry, IBook G4, 2010 MacBook pro] that I was given that don't have a use right now. I want to run a Minecraft server on them, but they do not have enough power for the use I want. Is there a way that I could get them to act like on computer so they can run more intensive programs?

Comment: Old Apple?  Not likely.  You have two boat anchors and a decent machine.  The 2010 Macbook pro isn't bad by modern standards.. it could probably do that on it's own I would think.  What you are talking about is "parallel computing" aka "clustered computing"  even if your hardware supported it, I doubt Minecraft would (anyone?? anyone?).  Are you sure that macbook pro won't work for a server on its own?

Comment: I don't think so. It is one of the less powerful models. I was able to get it to boot to Linux but it can hardly run single player. I will try it though.

Comment: I myself wouldn't try to run linux on it.  I would try to run something old like snow leopard and host minecraft from it.. but what do I know. ;)  I am not a mac guy even though I support them and own a macbook.   Good luck.  Oh..!  Also. you should be able to upgrade stuff on that 2010 with memory other people just have laying around.  It was before Apple locked stuff down.

Comment: I tried to use mac os. I just couldn't find a download for it. The system was given to me and I didn't know the password.

Comment: Another similar question: [Can I share CPU over network?](https://superuser.com/q/1064678/432690)